# What happens when I push from a tracking branch in Git to a different remote branch?

Tags: git

Say I have a tracking branch called devo-1 that tracks the remote's devo-1 branch. Suppose there's another branch in the same remote, called devo-2. I now perform the following:

1. `git checkout devo-1`
2. `git fetch origin`
3. `git pull origin devo-2`
4. `git push origin devo-2`

My questions:

- At step 2, this should update all origin/devo-* remote-tracking branches, correct?
- At step 3, this should get updates from **only** origin devo-2 (and not devo-1), correct?
- At step 4, this should push changes in devo-1 to **only** origin devo-2, correct?

Thanks!

Comment: Hm, three answers with yes, maybe and no for step 3 - probably a bit unclear what you asked for there... :)

Answer (score 3):

Short version: 1: yes, 2: maybe, 3: no.

---

Git's terminology is twisty and confusing.  You don't push to a "remote branch", you push to a branch on a remote.  Seems like a silly distinction but because the terminology is confusing, it's important to make sure.  (Just to be even *more* confusing, these "branches" all refer to labels attached to repositories, rather than the data structures one builds from the commit graphs contained in those repositories; but parts of those structures are *also* called "branches" at various times.)

To make things worse, `git fetch`, `git pull`, and `git push` are not quite symmetric, either.

We start out in your own `devo-1` branch (because of `git checkout devo-1`), although that does not matter until `git pull` invokes `git merge` below.

Then, assuming a standard setup (not a mirror or whatever):

```
git fetch origin
```

calls up the remote git on the internet-phone (or whatever), asks him "hey, what branch labels do you have", copies over commits and such as needed, and sticks a copy of his (local) branch labels in your (local) "remote-branch" labels under your `origin/` name-space.  That is, `origin/devo-1` and `origin/devo-2` are both updated—I assume both exist on `origin`—along with anything else that can be, while your git has this chance.

**(The answer to your first question is "yes".)**

The next command:

```
git pull origin devo-2
```

just runs a shell script, which in turn runs two commands:

- `git fetch` (with some arguments), then
- either `git merge` or `git rebase`, depending on your pull configuration.  I'm going to assume the former.

The first sub-part calls up the remote git on the internet-phone again.  This time it only brings over new stuff in the supplied branch, i.e., their copy of `devo-2`.  It's pretty likely there's nothing new there yet (you just did a full fetch), but if there is anything new, it then drops the new SHA-1 into the special `FETCH_HEAD` file, but *does not*<sup>1</sup> update your "remote branch" copy in `origin/devo-2`.

The second sub-part runs `git merge` to merge in their latest version.  This is the moral equivalent<sup>2</sup> of doing `git merge origin/devo-2`.  So now your `devo-1` is merged with the latest commit in their `devo-2`, as recorded in `FETCH_HEAD`.

(Or, if you're set up for rebase, it does that instead.)

**(The answer to your second question is "maybe, depending on precisely what you meant".)**

Although you get any new commits and other SHA-1 goodies needed, they're only written into `FETCH_HEAD`, *unless* you have a new (1.8.4 or later) git.  (See footnote 1.)

Last, your `git push`: you gave it two extra arguments, a remote and a refspec.  The remote is `origin`, so that's who it will call up on the internet-phone or whatever as before.  The refspec, though: that's `devo-2`, and *that* means `devo-2:devo-2` which (since I assume you have a local `devo-2` branch) means `refs/heads/devo-2:refs/heads/devo-2`.

This takes your local `devo-2` (**not** `devo-1`) and tries to send new stuff to the remote (he gets a chance to reject them) and point his `devo-2` branch label to the new tip commit.

**(The answer to your third question is "no".)**

In order to push what's in your `devo-1` to their `devo-2`, you need:

```
git push origin devo-1:devo-2
```

The refspec here means: "Send their git the SHA-1 you find by looking up my `devo-1`, and ask them to write it to their `devo-2`."

---

<sup>1</sup>Unless you have git 1.8.4 or newer, and then it *does* update `origin/devo-2`.  Fortunately, this doesn't matter here: even if there was new stuff, the next step uses `FETCH_HEAD` to refer to it, rather than using `origin/devo-2`.

<sup>2</sup>If you have git 1.8.4 or newer, it's the *real* equivalent.  Otherwise it depends on whether the second `fetch` actually brought new stuff in.

Answer (score 0):

> At step 2, this should update all origin/devo-* remote-tracking branches, correct?

Correct.  (Well, any remote tracking branches.  Not just those that start with "devo")

> At step 3, this should get updates from only origin devo-2 (and not devo-1), correct?

Correct. (Well, the remote devo-2 branch will be merged/rebased with your HEAD).

> At step 4, this should push changes in devo-1 to only origin devo-2, correct?

**Incorrect**.  `git push origin devo-1:devo-2` is what you're looking for.

`git push origin devo-2` is basically saying "push my local devo-2 branch to the remote devo-2 branch", or `git push origin devo-2:devo-2`.

Answer (score 0):

Step 2 - yes git-fetch will update all remote branches (unless you provide a refspec argument to limit what it fetches).

Step 3 - no, git-pull is essentially the same as git-fetch + git-merge, and the merge operation will operate on the current branch. So in this example the current branch is devo-1 and the command would then merge devo-2 into devo-1.

Step 4, no this will push your local devo-2 changes to origin/devo-2.

Answer (score 0):

- `git fetch` will not only update remote *tracking* branches, but all remote branches of that remote. Tracking usually means that a local branch belongs to a certain remote branch and consider that as the default, and supply additional status information.
- `git pull origin devo-2` will fetch again for `devo-2` and then merge the remote branch (`origin/devo-2`) into the current branch. So as you have checked out the local `devo-1` branch before, you will essentially merge the remote’s `devo-2` into that branch.
- `git push origin devo-2` will be equivalent to `git push origin devo-2:devo-2` which means that this will push your local `devo-2` to the remote’s `devo-2`. So no, your local and currently checked out branch `devo-1` will not be used for anything.